# Is there a method in jQuery Mobile that returns the current path?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm looking for a method in jQuery Mobile to get the path of the current page regardless of if it has been navigated to directly or loaded through Ajax.

So for both:

http://example.com/#/page1

and:

http://example.com/page1

the same path should be returned:

/page1

I know this can probably be extracted from location.href, but it will require some additional code so I'm wondering if there is a simpler more robust way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally found that you can get this by doing:

```
$('.ui-page-active').data('url')
```

Comment: You can also `$('.ui-page-active').data('absUrl')` to get absolute url of the active page.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for the current path or page id, you could use:

```
$.mobile.activePage[0].id
```

Answer (score 0):

It's `location.href` AND `location.hash`

There also is a generated `<base>` element that contains a `href` you should find helpful.

Mentioned here: http://jquerymobile.com/test/#docs/pages/docs-navmodel.html

Caution: it says the documentation needs to be updated.

Also - please read a bit about `progressive enhancement` on which JQM bases its idea, because you might not want to deal with links from javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
$.mobile.activePage[0].baseURI
```

Answer (score 0):

**$.mobile.activePage** doesn't work if you need to know page url before pageinit event. If you want to get current page url at any time you can use such a method:

```
getCurrentPageUri: function() {
    var currentUrl = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(window.location);
    var result = currentUrl.hash && currentUrl.hash.split("?")[0];
    return (result && result.substring(1)) || currentUrl.pathname;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution from Reoger Ertesvag didn't work for me as it has always the same value even after pageChange. I use this one instead and it works great:

```
$.mobile.activePage.data("url");
```

Be careful as it doesn't work on pageinit but on pageshow.